# Insecure ENV variable at setuid

Tags: linux, perl

i am using this code its working fine when i am running it from root but when i set root priviledges to it throws up an error saying "insecure $ENV{PATH} at line system "perl $qtool -d $mqueue_directory*$queue_id";"

my script is in path /scripts/deferred.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $qtool = "/usr/local/bin/qtool.pl";
my $mqueue_directory = "/var/spool/mqueue";
my $messages_removed = 0;
my @rf_id;
my @date;
my $temp
my @write_array;
my $to;
my $from;
use Untaint;
use File::Find;
# Recursively find all files and directories in $mqueue_directory
use Untaint;
find(\&wanted, $mqueue_directory);

sub wanted {
   # Is this a qf* file?
   if ( /^qf(\w{14})/ ) {
      my $qf_file = $_;
      my $queue_id = $1;
      my $deferred = 0;
      my $from_postmaster = 0;
      my $delivery_failure = 0;
      my $junk_mail = 0;
      open (QF_FILE, $_);
      while(<QF_FILE>) {
         $deferred = 1 if ( /^MTemporarily/ | /^Mhost map: lookup/ | /^MUser unknown/ );
         $delivery_failure = 1 if \
            ( /^H\?\?Subject: DELIVERY FAILURE: (User|Recipient)/ );
         if ( $deferred && $from_postmaster && $delivery_failure ) {
            $junk_mail = 1;
                     }
      $temp=$qf_file.':';
      if($junk_mail){
      while(<QF_FILE>){
      chomp;
      if(/rRFC822;/){
      $temp.=subdtr($_,9)
      }
      if(/H?D?Date:/){
      $temp.=':'.substr($_,10);
      push @write_array, $temp."\n";
      }
      }
      }
      }
      close (QF_FILE);
      my $subqueue_id = substr($queue_id,9);
      if ($junk_mail) {
         print "Removing $queue_id...\n";
         system "perl $qtool -d $mqueue_directory*$queue_id";
         $messages_removed++;
      }
   }
}
open (MYFILE,">/scripts/mail.txt");
print MYFILE "@write_array";
close (MYFILE);
$to='yagya@mydomain.in';
$from='system@mydomain.in';
$subject='deleted mails';

open(MAIL,"|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
print MAIL "@write_array\n";
close(MAIL);

print "\n$messages_removed total \"double bounce\" message(s) removed from ";
print "mail queue.\n";
```

Comment: Possible Duplikate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531142/setuid-to-perl-script

Answer (score 6):

Setuid programs automatically run in taint mode. It's all explained in [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html), including the text in your error message. Often, if you paste the error message into a search engine, you'll quickly find out what to do about it. You might also see [Insecure $ENV{ENV} while running with -T switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552197/insecure-envenv-while-running-with-t-switch).